# Can't read xlsx.file to a dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

I have a file with the name IE00BK1PV551_20210610.xlsx in the folder ETF.
I try to read it to a data frame.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('ETF/IE00BK1PV551_20210610.xlsx')
```

It doesn't work for me. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator'
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html,
you may have to specify the engine

```
pd.read_excel('ETF/IE00BK1PV551_20210610.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') for new excel files
```